# Find out which version of app was first installed - iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to change my app from a paid version to a free with ads. However, I don't want the people that originally paid for the app to get the ads.

I was thinking I could include a new update that has extra code that sets up some UserDefaults saying the version doesn't have ads and then do the update to the free version. But that doesn't seem like a very reliable solution.

Comment: have you used sqlite database in your application

Comment: I think there is not reliable way to achieve what you want.
What if user paid for your game and uninstalled it, and want to install again - but then he gets version with ads.
My opinion - release freemium version separatly and leave paid one as is.

Comment: No I have not. Would your suggestion have been - Check the created date on the rows?

Comment: @Wojciech - That is a very good point. I guess there is no solution without some kind of user accounts?

Comment: Yes you can check if there exists a particular table and then accordingly manipulate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no reliable method to detect whether someone paid for your app or downloaded it later when the price has been changed to free. For this reason I have decided to create two separate entries in the app store.

Answer (score 1):

I think, it depends on minimum OS version, that your program can be run on. For iOS 5.0 and later you can try to use iCloud to store some flag about purchased version. It allows you to set this flag not only for one device, but for the user's account.

Or you can store this info in the keychain to get it later. But in this case your user will not be able to have no ADs on some other device with his(her) account.

Anyway, as far as I know, you need to create an update for your app first to write this flag anywhere. And only in some time make an update with ADs.

I will be glad to see comments if someone has another thoughts about this issue.

Comment: I think using both options would be a pretty decent solution. There doesn't seem to be completely foolproof method. I'm starting to think having a free and a separate paid for version would be better.

Comment: if it is not a problem for you to support both versions - it is the best solution, I think.